# TCP port forwarding in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to make TCP forwarder in C#, which opens external website and redirects it to localhost. Like:

```
http://localhost:8080/http://google.com
```

Which opens google.com in localhost.

I've tried the following source: http://blog.brunogarcia.com/2012/10/simple-tcp-forwarder-in-c.html

But it uses sockets and raw data, so I'm unable to modify the HTTP packets (because they're compressed with gzip). Is there a more friendly way to parse the packets with some .NET class which allows me to modify the request headers or the received data?

Comment: Are you looking for a reverse proxy? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31329/Simple-Reverse-Proxy-in-C-description-and-depl

Comment: I guess that's how it's called. But I don't want to use IIS or any exernal server.

Comment: I think this is what you are after: https://github.com/niik/switchboard